# React JS, load json data then manipulate it

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reactjs

Started to play around with react, just learning the small syntax stuff at the moment, im stuck on AJAX requests with data displaying.

The console gives me an error saying the local version of test.json cannot be found. It is in the same directory as the header.js file

```
//header.js
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery'; 

var theData = [];

var Header = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
        data: null
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url:  "./test.json",
            success: function(data) {
            theData.push(data);
            console.log(theData);
            }
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
        <div>
            <div id="theData" className="theData"></div>
              {theData.someValue}
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test.json` might be in the same directory as `header.js`, but your code is running client-side and the client (browser) has no idea of what `test.json` is.

Instead, you should define an endpoint in your server-side logic to read the contents of `test.json` and return it back to the client as a JSON object. In your client-side logic, the URL property in your current XHR should be replaced with the URI to the endpoint.

Side note: your component as-is won't display any data after the XHR is complete. `theData` will be properly mutated but it won't trigger a component rerender. You should instead associate your XHR response JSON with component state (which you initialized properly in `getInitialState`), and React will rerender accordingly when its value is modified.

**Update** with a code example, assuming your server is [Express](http://expressjs.com/).

On the server:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const app = ...

app.get('/name-this-endpoint-appropriately', (req, res) => {
    const json = fs.readFileSync('test.json', 'utf8');
    res.send(json);
});
```

On the client (with fixes as mentioned in the side note above):

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery'; 

var Header = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            data: []
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url:  "/name-this-endpoint-appropriately",
            success: (data) => this.setState({data})
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
        <div>
            <div id="theData" className="theData"></div>
              {this.state.data.someValue}
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: great explanation do you have any links to resources with code examples?

Comment: Great iv'e got it working on an API i deployed, but how do i use it with local API's?